# How to identify the WPF custom controls using coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to Automate a WPF application with Coded UI Test 2010.I am able to hand code to identify the WPF controls in the Application However I could not able to find some controls.

I did some r&d and got to know that few are custom controls in the application.This was the reason why the playback failed.

I tried with record and playback too but no use.
I got a reference link to resolve the problem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx#recordandplayback

But I didn't understand from where we need to start.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI does support WPF, so as long as there are identifiable properties of the object you are pointing to, it should then be just a matter of properly defining the object in code.  For example, a custom object could be defined as, at it's root, a XamlControl.  You lose out on some of the extension methods available to controls like ComboBoxes (SelectedItem(), SelectedIndex(), etc.), but it should still work.  There's some good information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.windowsruntimecontrols.xamlcontrol.aspx) regarding the inheritance of Xaml controls.

For example, define your control by it's ID or title:

```
public XamlControl myCustomControl
{
    get
    {
        XamlControl target = new XamlControl();
        target.SearchProperties["title"] = "hard to find control";
        return target;
    }
}
```